# ORACLE 01843. 00000 - "not a valid month"

Tags: sql, oracle, date-format, ora-01843

```
CREATE TABLE  EventRequest(      
  EVENTNO VARCHAR2(8) constraint EventNoNotNull Not Null,
  DATEHELD DATE constraint DateHelNotNull Not Null,
  DATEREQ DATE CONSTRAINT DateReqNotNull Not Null,
  CUSTNO VARCHAR2(8),
  FACNO VARCHAR2(8),
  DATEAUTH DATE,
  STATUS VARCHAR2(16) CONSTRAINT StatusNotNull Not Null,
  ESTCOST VARCHAR2(30) CONSTRAINT EstCost Not Null,
  ESTAUDIENCE VARCHAR2(8) CONSTRAINT EstAudienceZero CHECK (ESTAUDIENCE>0),
  BUDNO VarCHar2(8),

  CONSTRAINT PK_EventRequest primary Key (EventNo),
  constraint fk_EventCustNo Foreign Key (CustNo) REFERENCES Customer (CustNo),
  constraint fk_EventFacNo foreign key(FacNo) References Facility (FacNo),
  CONSTRAINT checkinstatus CHECK (Status in ('Approved', 'Denied', 'Pending'))
);
```

This is my table where I'm trying to insert

```
Insert into EVENTREQUEST(EVENTNO, DATEHELD, DATEREQ, 
                         CUSTNO, FACNO, DATEAUTH,
                         STATUS, ESTCOST, ESTAUDIENCE, BUDNO)
values ('E100', to_date('25-OCT-13','DD-MON-RR'), to_date('06-JUN-13','DD-MON-RR'),
        'C100', 'F100',  to_date('08-JUN-13','DD-MON-RR'),
        'Approved', 5000, 80000, 'B1000');
```

I'm using Sql Developer and Oracle Developer Day on VirtualBox.
I changed my session too with this command but nothing happened

```
ALTER SESSION SET NLS_DATE_FORMAT = 'DD-MON-RR HH24:MI:SS';
```

Comment: The way i see that you are trying to insert date with format DD-MON-YY, since no time being passed, have you tried just to use 
Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E100','25-OCT-13','06-JUN-13','C100','F100','08-JUN-13','Approved',5000,80000,'B1000');
And see if it solved the problem

Comment: You can use an explicit literal, such as '`DATE '2013-10-24`'.

Comment: Thank you @adesst  but it's not working! I'm using this Date_format because Time is needed in other tables.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It works but i have a .txt file where all my insert statements are, this means I have to change each one of them?

Comment: can you use cast in your query..and try with that instead of to_date..

Comment: try this way...Insert into EVENTREQUEST (EVENTNO,DATEHELD,DATEREQ,CUSTNO,FACNO,DATEAUTH,STATUS,ESTCOST,ESTAUDIENCE,BUDNO) values ('E100',cast('25-OCT-13' as date ),cast('06-JUN-13' as date),'C100','F100',cast('08-JUN-13' as date),'Approved',5000,80000,'B1000');

Comment: Resolved with this command: alter session set nls_language=AMERICAN;

Comment: Alessandro . . . Can you add that as an answer to your question and accept it?  I was thinking that NLS_DATE_FORMAT used localization settings for the month name, but Oracle documentation is hard to decipher (and I only have limited experience with Oracle and internationalization).  You can answer and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved with this command: alter session set nls_language=AMERICAN;